# can I just resave the entries i the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails project and I recently decided to add `blog_id` to comments table to allow you to pull all comments that belong to a specific blog. The problem I am facing is what do I do for comments already in the database? Can I just do:

```
Comment.find_each(&:save)
```

I think not because it doesn't know which blog it originally belonged to - even though the relationship has been updated to say: blogs has many comments and comments belongs to blog

Based on that relationship can I just do the above code in a rake task?

Comment: You can't have your app guess which blog each comment belongs to, can you? Is there any basic filter that will make a set of comments correspond to any specific blog?

Comment: I wouldn't asking if I knew. So I am assuming no.

Comment: I feared so... Your existing comments cannot be otherwise handled but edited one by one. If you want them to correspond to blogs, you will need to have the blog assigned manually.

Comment: well each comment belongs to a post and each post belongs to a blog can I do it through the post  - grab the blog id and assign it to the comment?

Comment: ahhh, this is different. Yes, you can. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Comment.all.each do |comment|
    comment.blog = comment.post.blog
    comment.save
end
```

But all this is not really necessary. You could have the comments assigned to the blog without the `blog_id`, simply by the following:

blog.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, through: :posts
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :blog
has_many   :comments
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :post

def blog
    post.blog
end
```

This way, you will have (per case):

```
@blog.posts
@blog.comments

@post.comments
@post.blog

@comment.post
@comment.blog
```